# Updated in a database [update ... set] java

Tags: java, database

I have a problem with my java code. When I do a database update but they don't work up . I used the three methods that I found on the internet and still they have not worked!
Help me
thank you in advance

```
package HLR_SERVEUR;
public class model_HLR{

    public void setupdate(String[] information) 
    {
        int imsdn_values,cins,kcs,kis;
        long IMSI_values=0;

        this.IMSI_values = Long.parseLong(information[0]);
        this.imsdn_values = Integer.parseInt(information[1]);
        this.kis = Integer.parseInt(information[2]);
        this.kcs = Integer.parseInt(information[3]);
        this.service = new String(information[4]);
        this.nom = new String(information[5]);
        this.prenom = new String(information[6]);
        this.cins = Integer.parseInt(information[7]);
        System.out.println(this.IMSI_values);
        System.out.println(this.imsdn_values);
        System.out.println(this.kis);
        System.out.println(this.kcs);
        System.out.println(this.service);
        System.out.println(this.nom);
        System.out.println(this.prenom);
        System.out.println(this.cins);

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            dbConnect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/abonnes", "root","");
            dbStatement = dbConnect.createStatement();

            /*
                test 1: 

                 PreparedStatement prepareStatement = (PreparedStatement)                                                     dbConnect.prepareStatement("Update sim set ISMIDN="+this.imsdn_values +", KI="+this.kis +",KC="+this.kcs+",SERVICE='"+this.service +"',nom='"+this.nom +"',prenom='"+this.prenom +"',cin="+this.cins +" Where IMSI="+this.IMSI_value+"");

            k=prepareStatement.executeUpdate();
                test 2: 
               PreparedStatement checkDB = (PreparedStatement)   dbConnect.prepareStatement( "UPDATE sim set ISMIDN= ? ,KI= ?,KC= ?,SERVICE= ?,nom= ?,prenom= ?,cin= ? Where ISMI= ? ");

            checkDB.setInt(1,this.imsdn_values);
            checkDB.setInt(2,this.kis);
            checkDB.setInt(3,this.kcs);
            checkDB.setString(4,this.service);
            checkDB.setString(5,this.nom);
            checkDB.setString(6,this.prenom); 
            checkDB.setInt(7,this.cins);
            checkDB.setLong(8,this.IMSI_values);
            k=checkDB.executeUpdate();
            */  
                 /*    test 3: */

            dbStatement=dbConnect.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

            ResultSet uprs = dbStatement
                    .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sim where ISMI ='"
                            + this.IMSI_values + "'");


                uprs.moveToInsertRow();
                uprs.updateInt("ISMIDN", this.imsdn_values);
                uprs.updateInt("KI", this.kis);
                uprs.updateInt("KC", this.kcs);
                uprs.updateString("SERVICE", this.service);
                uprs.updateString("nom", this.nom);
                uprs.updateString("prenom", this.prenom);
                uprs.updateInt("cin", this.cins);

                uprs.insertRow();
                uprs.beforeFirst();

            dbStatement.close();
            dbConnect.close();


        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(View.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(View.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

---

mai 12, 2015 12:20:55 AM HLR_SERVEUR.model_HLR setupdate
GRAVE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'ISMI' cannot be null
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:931)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2941)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1623)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1715)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3249)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1268)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1455)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1440)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.UpdatableResultSet.insertRow(UpdatableResultSet.java:739)
    at HLR_SERVEUR.model_HLR.setupdate(model_HLR.java:304)
    at HLR_SERVEUR.AbonnePanel_Rechercher.actionPerformed(AbonnePanel_Rechercher.java:401)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

---

problems mai 12, 2015 1:42:15 AM HLR_SERVEUR.model_HLR setupdate GRAVE: null com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '216011100258963' for key 'PRIMARY

Comment: Please read about rules of stacvoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the log that you posted as answer, column **ISMI** is a mandatory field for your database table, it seems like a **primary key**.

You need something like:

```
uprs.updateInt("ISMI", someValue);
```

to complete your new row data.

Please also note that primary key **must be unique** in table.

Comment: problems mai 12, 2015 1:42:15 AM HLR_SERVEUR.model_HLR setupdate
GRAVE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '216011100258963' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: The error message explained everything, you have set the duplicate value to primary key.